# sharepoint 3.0 site restore/import trouble

Tags: sharepoint, restore, wss-3.0

We have some old sharepoint data (from a WSS 3.0 SP1 or SP2 install), that I need to restore. Problem is: This is a time management site, and one of the fields automatically pics up the user name of the user that enters data, and this is used to keep track of who worked when.

Now, when I import this into my temporary sharepoint 3.0 server, these fields are blanked, and the creator of the element is replaced by my admin user (the account that ran the import job).

So, to the question: Is there any way at all to grab hold of these data before the sharepoint import job "destroys" them? I'm using stsadm -o import.

I don't care if I have to pick the database itself apart manually, I just need to know if it's possible to get hold of these fields with data intact from my export files...

(Backup you say? It was deleted loong ago. This sharepoint export is all we have...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think the exoprt hold that information at all.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the -includeusersecurity switch? It will have effect only if used when the export was done.

Comment: I have tried it, to no avail. Which means it probably wasn't done on the export.